# Reading a textfile and adding a new line everytime ';' appears

Tags: python

I have a text file with a lot of information. The different part of the text file are separated with a ';' like this:

```
ID;Art no;Title;Status;Created
```

I would like to add a new line everytime ';' appear.

So the result should look like this:

```
ID;
Art no;
Title;
Status;
Created
```

I have no clue how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simple substitution problem; replace semicolons with semicolons plus a newline:

```
line.replace(';', ';\n')
```